# Haskell program to find the position of an element in a list

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function to find the position of one specific element in a list.
i was writing like this:

```
findPos list elt | list == [] = -1
                 | head list == elt = 0
                 | otherwise = 1 + (findPos (tail list) elt)
```

but how to do in the case that the element is repeated within the list?
For example: `list= [2,4,9,4,8]` and i want the position of the element "4", then has 2 position : second and fourth. How would be a simply function for that?

Comment: Consult your teacher as to what they want. Sensible options include (a) just returning the first position located; or (b) returning a list of indices.

Comment: If you reverse the order of your arguments, then your function may also be more useful for currying, because then you can do: `let findx = find 'x'` and have a function that searches for 'x' in a given list. Your way is more useful if you want to create a function that has the set to test given, and tests an item for membership, e.g. for whitelists / blacklists.

Comment: http://www.codecatalog.net/239/

Answer (score 9):

You should return a lazy-evaluated list of indexes for elements that are matching.

The easy functional way of doing it is to index first the list using `zip [0..]` then filter that zipped list on the second element and finaly remove the second elements just to keep the indexes.

```
-- first version
findPos list elt = map fst $ filter ((elt==).snd) $ zip [0..] list
-- second version, using list comprehensions
findPos list elt = [index | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == elt]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make it return a list of indices. To make this work, you'll need to change a couple of things in the function:

1. Instead of -1 return the empty list for the empty case (returning -1 is a bad idiom anyway, you should have returned a Maybe instead as that is more meaningful).
2. Instead of calling `findPos` recursively and adding 1 to the result, you should create a helper function taking a counter (which starts at 0) and increase the counter by 1.
3. When you find the element, instead of returning 0, you should return the current value of the counter prepended to the result of recursing on the tail of the list (with an increased counter).

However this functionality already exists in `Data.List` and is called `elemIndices`. So unless this is a pure learning exercise or homework, you don't need to reimplement this at all.

Comment: I'd add that the reason to use a helper function is because by passing the whole state of your calculation, you can achieve "continuation passing style" (look it up), which can be automatically optimised to avoid building stack frames (instead it is implemented in the same way as a loop). This is not essential, but it will be more efficient.

Comment: @Marcin: The reason to use the helper function is that without it you'd have to increase each element in the resulting list after each recursive call, which would be 1. less readable and harder to understand and 2. much less efficient. I don't see any connection to CPS.

Comment: (a) it's only necessary for that reason if you change the function to return a list (which is not what the original implementation did); (b) if you're wrapping everything up as arguments, you might as well capture the benefits of CPS.

Comment: @Marcin: The question was how to make it return a list (or how to make it handle multiple indices anyway, which implies a list). Also if you kept returning a single index and made the function tail recursive using a helper function, there still would be no CPS involved.

Comment: The question does not imply a list. One other option would be to just return the first index. If you pass the whole state and it's tail recursive, that's cps.

Comment: @Marcin: No, it's not. CPS is when you pass the continuation as an explicit argument (in form of a function) to the function you're calling. This tends to make the call a tail-call, but it hardly implies that every tail-call is related to CPS.

Comment: Regarding multiple indices: Returning the first index is what the OP's code currently does. I would not consider ignoring subsequent indices handling them.

Comment: @sepp2k: Re CPS: I stand corrected. Re multiple indices: If it's documented, just returning the first is a way of handling them. An alternative would be to return both the index, and the tail of the list. There's more than one way to tackle this.

Comment: @Marcin: Sure, but ignoring the rest of the indices is clearly not what the OP wanted. Otherwise he wouldn't have asked (Why would he ask when he already has what he wants?). Returning a tuple is an option, yes, but in my opinion returning a list of indices is the preferable option in most situations and it is the one I have chosen for this answer.

Comment: @sepp2k: (a) It's not the only answer, which is what your answer suggests ("You should make it return a list of indices"); (b) beginners often don't realise there are options, rather than one right way.

Comment: @Marcin: Fair enough, I've changed "should" to "could" to signify that it's just one option.

Comment: @sepp2k:very good advices.i understood that returning -1 or 0 ,is not professional language.i put that. only to indicate the stopping of the function .Returning Maybe ,is the same indicated ? or means something more?.i understand that with this function i get a list of index (all the possitions )only for one element .If i need to ask for many elements at the same time and i introduce as argument a list of elements (instead of one)in this case would be better to get not only the list of indices but along with each index should be there the element associated with this position.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a fold:

```
findPos :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
findPos elem = reverse . fst . foldl step ([],0) where
    step (is,i) e = (if e == elem then i:is else is, succ i)
```

Writing in a way that feels like a while loop in imperative languages is possible, but rather verbose:

```
findPos elem list = reverse $ thrd $ until finished step (list,0,[]) where
   finished (x,_,_) = null x
   step (e:es, c, acc) = (es, succ c, if e == elem then c:acc else acc) 
   thrd (_,_,x) = x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is from Kru.
I suggest another idea for finding the first position of a element (not all positions), if this element is in the list.

Assume the element is in the list :

```
indexOf elt list = length $ takeWhile (/=elt) list
```

The list is traversed from the beginning to the first occurrence of elt, but it stops when the elt is found.